# Python: Trouble indexing a list from .split()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on a folder rename program that will crawl a directory, and rename specific words to their abbreviated version. These abbreviations are kept in a dictionary. When I try to replace `mylist[mylist.index(w)]` with the `abbreviation`, it replaces the entire list. The list shows 2 values, but it is treating them like a single index. Any help would be appreciated, as I am very new to Python.

My current test environment has the following:
**c:\test\Accounting 2018**

My expected result when this is completed, is **c:\test\Acct 2018**

```
import os


keyword_dict = {
    'accounting': 'Acct',
    'documents': 'Docs',
    'document': 'Doc',
    'invoice': 'Invc',
    'invoices': 'Invcs',
    'operations': 'Ops',
    'administration': 'Admin',
    'estimate': 'Est',
    'regulations': 'Regs',
    'work order': 'WO'
}


path = 'c:\\test'

def format_path():
    for kw in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        #split the output to separate the '\'
        usable_path = kw[0].split('\\')
        #pull out the last folder name
        string1 = str(usable_path[-1])
        #Split this output based on ' '
        mylist = [string1.lower().split(" ")]
        #Iterate through the folders to find any values in dictionary
        for i in mylist:
            for w in i:
                if w in keyword_dict.keys():
                    mylist[i.index(w)] = keyword_dict.get(w)
                    print(mylist)


format_path()
```

When I use `print(mylist)` prior to the index replacement, I get `['accounting', '2018']`, and `print(mylist[0])` returns the **same result**.
 After the index replacement, the `print(mylist)` returns `['acct]` the `['2018']` is now gone as well.

Why is it treating the list values as a single index?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the following but it should point to the right direction. But first, not sure if it is a good idea spacing is the way to go (Accounting 2018) could come up as accounting2018 or accounting_2018. Better to use regular expression. Anyway, here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
import os


keyword_dict = {
    'accounting': 'Acct',
    'documents': 'Docs',
    'document': 'Doc',
    'invoice': 'Invc',
    'invoices': 'Invcs',
    'operations': 'Ops',
    'administration': 'Admin',
    'estimate': 'Est',
    'regulations': 'Regs',
    'work order': 'WO'
}


path = 'c:\\test'

def format_path():

    for kw in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        #split the output to separate the '\'
        usable_path = kw[0].split('\\')

        #pull out the last folder name
        string1 = str(usable_path[-1])

        #Split this output based on ' '
        mylist = string1.lower().split(" ") #Remove [] since you are creating a list within a list for no reason

        #Iterate through the folders to find any values in dictionary

        for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
            abbreviation=keyword_dict.get(mylist[i],'')
            if abbreviation!='': #abbrevaition exists so overwrite it
                mylist[i]=abbreviation


        new_path=" ".join(mylist) #create new path (i.e. ['Acct', '2018']==>Acct 2018

        usable_path[len(usable_path)-1]=new_path #replace the last item in the original path then rejoin the path
        print("\\".join(usable_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
import re, os
regex = "|".join(keyword_dict.keys())
repl =  lambda x : keyword_dict.get(x.group().lower())

path = 'c:\\test'
[re.sub(regex,repl, i[0],re.I) for i in os.walk(path)]
```

You need to ensure the above is working.(So far it is working as expected) before you can `rename`